# TextInputLayout com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have update my sdk and now I can't use `TextInputLayout` from design support library. It was working fine before I updated.

It gives error in XML file that `Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

here is my **XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.edittest.MainActivity" >

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fNameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was for sure `SupportDesignLibrary` problem. new update got me that error. as I imported old library it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

MockView extends View object. It was working previously, you need to wait for an update of layout bridge classes with the new sdk update.